# Почему не загружается pdf в opencart 2?

Tags: opencart

Пробую загрузить pdf но выдает такая ошибка [prntscr.com/cg2euf](http://prntscr.com/cg2euf)
Подскажите как убрать эту ошибку? В настройках [prntscr.com/cg2gqk](http://prntscr.com/cg2gqk) все норм.

Comment: А в разрешенных MIME есть `application/pdf`?

Comment: Да есть http://prntscr.com/cg34w8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя на вкладке Сервер указываем какие файлы разрешаем, но оно НЕ РАБОТАЕТ.

Надо ещё открыть файл  `sait.loc\admin\controller\common\filemanager.php` и на строках:

1. `37` http://prntscr.com/cg3uhh;
2. `234` http://prntscr.com/cg3tzt;
3. `247` http://prntscr.com/cg3u5e;

добавить свой тип файлов.